# No puedo acceder a MySQL sin root

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, configuración, linux-mint

Hola amigos tengo un problema cuando trato de acceder a mi MySQL me da algunos errores.

Tengo instalada la versión:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

en un sistema operativo Linux Mint 19. Le describo los siguientes errores que me presenta al intentar acceder:

## 1 Acceso desde consola:

```
mysql -u root -h localhost
```

Retorna: `ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

## 2 Desde el phpMyadmin

Accediendo a http://localhost/phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## 3 Desde Navicat

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## 4 La única forma como pude acceder:

Accediendo con el método #1 pero haciendo antes acceso al root de mi sistema `sudo su` sin el super usuario no puedo entrar.

Espero que alguien me ayude, necesito que la configuración me funcione en phpMyadmin y en el Navicat que es lo mas que utilizo.

Gracias de ante mano por la ayuda que puedan brindarme.

Answer (score 1):

Es probable que no tengas los permisos para acceder. Prueba a entrar con sudo desde consola y dar permisos siguiendo una instrucción como esta:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Una vez hayas hecho eso, vuelve a probar el acceso tanto en terminal (sin sudo) como en el resto de metodos.

Otra alternativa que te propongo es crear un usuario nuevo y darle los permisos, con los comandos que te he puesto arriba, ya que muchas veces el root que viene en la instalación de mysql tiene limitaciones de acceso por seguridad.

Answer (score 0):

Instalé algunos paquetes que me faltaban:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mysql
```

Se me habían olvidado instalar, y ahora abre la interfaz de phpMyadmin, aparte hice las instrucciones que me diste lfpp y dijo todo OK!, pero sigo sin poder acceder.

También modifique la contraseña de acceso con root con `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string= 'admin' WHERE User = 'root';` todo OK!, pero igual no entra.

## ACTUALIZACION

Modifiqué algunas cosas mas y logré solucionarlo creé un nuevo usuario y ahora abre bien pero me da algunos mensajes de alertas en el phpmyadmin:

Aplique: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Irwing no hagas preguntas en la seccion de respuestas, si crees que tu nueva pregunta no se va mucho del tema de la anterior simplemente edita tu pregunta. En caso de que sea una pregunta un poco diferente puedes crear otra pregunta ! :)